# How to use the css selector to extract urls with python's scrapy?

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

In order to learn scrapy I am crawling all the elements of this website:http://quotes.toscrape.com/random

However, I do not understand how to crawl the author url bio. I tried to use the css selector:

```
>>> response.css('a::attr(href)').extract()
['/', '/login', '/author/Ralph-Waldo-Emerson', '/tag/life/page/1/', '/tag/regrets/page/1/', 'https://www.goodreads.com/quotes', 'https://scrapinghub.com']
```

Then:

```
>>> response.css('small.quote>span>a::attr(href)').extract()
```

Nevertheless, I am not getting the author's bio url. Thus, how can I get the aforementioned url with the css selector?.

**UPDATE**

I already know that I can do:

```
response.css('a::attr(href)').extract()[2]
```

However, I guess this is not robust. Any idea of how to get the bio link?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work:

```
>>> os.path.dirname(response.url)
'http://quotes.toscrape.com'

>> response.css('a::attr(href)').extract()[2]
u'/author/Bob-Marley'

>>> os.path.dirname(response.url) + response.css('a::attr(href)').extract()[2]
u'http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Bob-Marley'
```